# What does an image pose (camera to world) mean?

Tags: computer-vision, matrix, image

I have 1000 2D images of a 3D scene. For each image, I have pose (camera to world) as follows:

```
[[-9.55421e-01  1.19616e-01 -2.69932e-01  2.65583e+00]
 [ 2.95248e-01  3.88339e-01 -8.72939e-01  2.98160e+00]
 [ 4.07581e-04 -9.13720e-01 -4.06343e-01  1.36865e+00]
 [ 0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  1.00000e+00]]
```

What does this matrix represent? Does it tell us something about relation between the 2D image and 3D scene?

Comment: That's a projection matrix (concretely, a [camera matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix)) $\rightarrow$ it is used to project 3D points (in homogeneous coordinates) into the image plane.

Comment: So I have this matrix for each image. Does that mean that in order to project any point in 3D to image plane, I would need this matrix?

Comment: Using this matrix, can I find out the camera coordinates of the image in 3D?

Comment: Yes, in order to project a 3D point, $P$ (which is in homogeneous coordinates) into the image plane we just multiply it by the camera matrix, $C$ : $p = C\,P$, where $p$ is the location in the image where the point $P$ gets projected into. Regarding the second question, I don't understand what do you mean by: camera coordinates of the image in 3D.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I have a description of an object in a 3D scene (written by annotators), and while they wrote that we recorded camera matrix, camera center, look at, and dof to help us figure out where they were looking in the scene. For each scene, I have about 1000 2D images, each image gives a different view of the scene. I’m trying to create a training set of only 1 image per scene. I want to find the image that closely matches with the recorded camera parameters. How do I do that using recorded camera parameters and pose (camera matrix) of each image?

Comment: With the information given and if the camera used in order to take the 1000 images is the same, then you can find the camera that was closest to the object having a look at the projection of extreme points of the object. 

Imagine that the camera was very far from the object, then the projection of the object into the image will occupy a smaller number of pixels than if the camera was close to the object (however, note that this is an approximate solution)

Comment: Yes, it’s the same camera. So from what I understand, I take a few points (boundary points) of the object, project them onto 2D plane using the recorded camera matrix and also using camera matrix for each image. Then I calculate Euclidean distance between two points on image plane? If that’s correct, I just multiply the 3D point with camera matrices to get 2D points? No need of other camera parameters that were recorded too, such as center, look at, dof?

Comment: Is there any way to compare the two matrices (one that was recorded with description and one from image) to find how “close” they are, without projecting 3D points to image plane?

Comment: Yes, but this would only be valid if the points are taken w.r.t. camera coordinate system. Moreover, note that this is a gross approximation because points belonging to the same object may get projected very closely into the image plane depending on the position and orientation of the camera. If this is the case then I don't recommend you this method and I hope someone else give you the help needed.

Comment: That makes sense. I feel like we should be able to determine the closest images from recorded camera matrix by looking at just these two matrices. I just don’t how to do that or what I’m calculating.

Comment: Any ideas on my last comment?

Comment: I'll try to think about it, but no ideas, sorry.